# [h2o-3 ]Is there an existing solution to swaping two vectors in h2o-3?

Tags: java, frame, swap, h2o, vec

Lets say theres a Frame `fr` consisting of 3 vectors with column names "a" "b" "c". I have an `MRTask` giving me a new vector. `Vec new_vec_a = FooReturningNewVec(fr.vec("a"))`. Now I want to swap `fr.vec("a")` with `new_vec_a`.

Can I use an already existing method, if not how would you suggest on creating this method.